# C++ class name injection

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

According to the standard [class]/2:

> … The class-name is also inserted into the scope of the class itself; this is known as the *injected-class-name*.…

Moreover, [basic.scope.pdecl]/9:

> The point of declaration for an *injected-class-name* (Clause 9) is immediately following the opening brace of the class definition.

Finally, [basic.lookup.classref]/3 and its example:

> If the unqualified-id is ~ *type-name*, the *type-name* is looked up …

```
struct A { };
struct B {
    struct A { };
    void f(::A* a);
};
void B::f(::A* a) {
    a-> ~ A(); // OK: lookup in *a finds the injected-class-name
}
```

So far, we can gather:

1. In the scope of a class A, there exists a name A.
2. That name is declared at the opening of the definition brace of class A.
3. That name names a type.

If the above is correct, then **why does the following code fails to compile** (in MSVC2015):

```
struct inj
{};

typedef struct inj::inj inj2;
```

The error message

> Error C2039   '{ctor}': is not a member of 'inj'

seems to be at odds with the standard:

> Note: For example, the constructor is not an acceptable lookup result in an elaborated-type-specifier so the constructor would not be used in place
>   of the injected-class-name. —end note

Comment: because it's not legal c++, probably.

Comment: what paragraph is that note from?

Comment: Probably just another MSVC bug. Both g++ and clang++ accept the example.

Comment: @sp2danny [class.qual]p2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the following code compiles and runs correctly in other compilers, it is a bug in MSVC2015.

```
#include <boost/type_index.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct inj
{
    int g;
};

typedef struct inj::inj inj2;

int main()
{

    inj2 ii;
    std::cout << boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr<decltype(ii)>().pretty_name() << '\n';
}
```

---

UPDATE: [Reported as bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1618414).

Comment: There is a virtually identical code example in the standard itself (3.4.3.1) and MSVC fails to compile it, so it should be preferably included in the bug report.