# Boost serialization base_object unspecialized template - why does it work?

Tags: c++, templates, serialization, boost

I am trying to understand why this minimal example compiles:

https://godbolt.org/z/xYeo53GPv

```
template <typename T>
struct Base {
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <class ARCHIVE>
    void serialize(ARCHIVE& ar, const unsigned int /*version*/) {}
};

struct Derived : public Base<int> {
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <class ARCHIVE>
    void serialize(ARCHIVE& ar, const unsigned int /*version*/) {
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_BASE_OBJECT_NVP(Base);
    }
};
```

Since `Base` is a templated type, how is it possible to pass it into `BOOST_SERIALIZATION_BASE_OBJECT_NVP(Base)` without specifying the template parameters?

For reference, in Boost 1.77 that macro expands into

```
#define BOOST_SERIALIZATION_BASE_OBJECT_NVP(name)           \
    boost::serialization::make_nvp(                         \
        BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(name),                           \
        boost::serialization::base_object<name >(*this)     \
    )
```

and `boost::serialization::base_object` is defined:

```
template<class Base, class Derived>
typename detail::base_cast<Base, Derived>::type &
base_object(Derived &d)
{
    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(( is_base_and_derived<Base,Derived>::value));
    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(! is_pointer<Derived>::value);
    typedef typename detail::base_cast<Base, Derived>::type type;
    detail::base_register<type, Derived>::invoke();
    return access::cast_reference<type, Derived>(d);
}
```

where `Base` is `Base` is (I think) getting explicitly substituted as `Base` and `Derived` is getting deduced as `Derived`.

To reiterate, how does this compile even though we are specifying the template parameters of `Base`?

Comment: Because `A` inherits `Base<int>`, `Base<int>` can be simplified to `Base` in the scope of A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, it's not "unspecialized" but "unparameterized" which is actually okay because of a language feature. This mechanism is known as ***class name injection*** and is specified by the standard.

Like @康桓瑋 mentioned, the `Base` can be used without the template arguments within the class declaration.

For some background, see e.g.

- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name
- [C++ class name injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31769853/c-class-name-injection/31770521)